# Problem with removing a subview and then adding it again

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a problem with removing a subview, or more precisely with checking if it is still there after having deleted it.

My app first adds a subview to self.view.

```
[self.view addSubview:tabsClippedView];
```

Then it adds another subview to this subview (to which it adds several buttons as subviews, but I guess this is unimportant in this context):

```
[tabsClippedView addSubview:tabsView];
```

Finally, I have a method which allows the tabsView to be deleted and then created again. I need to do this so as to update the number of buttons in that tabsView (as the user can delete buttons). The method looks basically like this:

```
[self.tabsView removeFromSuperview];
```

After that I call a method called showTabs (which I already called in the very beginning of the app in order to add the subViews). This is where it all becomes problematic and where my app crashes (I get no error in the debug console, so I don't really know what the issue is...):

```
    if ([tabsClippedView isDescendantOfView:self.view]) {
    NSLog(@"There is already a tabsClippedView.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"There is no tabsClippedView. I'll add one...");
    [self initTabsClippedView];
}
```

**This is where the app crashes: when trying to assess if tabsView isDescendantOfView (I don't get any of the following logs):**

```
if ([tabsView isDescendantOfView:tabsClippedView]) {
    NSLog(@"There is already a tabsView");
} else {
    NSLog(@"There is no tabsView for the buttons. I'll add one including buttons.");
    [self initTabs];
}
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions where the problem could be.

---

**EDIT:**

These are the methods to set up my views:

```
-(void) initTabsClippedView { // sets up tabsClippedView

NSLog(@"initTabsClippedView method started...");

CGRect tabsClippedFrame = CGRectMake(258,30,70,81*6);
tabsClippedView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tabsClippedFrame] autorelease];
tabsClippedView.clipsToBounds = true;

[self.view addSubview:tabsClippedView];

NSLog(@"initTabsClippedView method ended.");
```

}

```
    -(void) initTabs {          

    NSLog(@"initTabs started. Adding buttons to tabsClippedView...");

    CGRect tabsFrame = CGRectMake(-30,0,50,480);
    tabsView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tabsFrame] autorelease];
    [tabsClippedView addSubview:tabsView];  
// sets up buttons in tabsClippedView
```

And this is where I delete the tabsClippedView (triggered by a button found in tabsClippedView):

```
 -(void)tabDelete:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{

                                    button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-30, 0);                 

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){


                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0
                                               delay:0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                          animations:^{

                                              [self.tabsView removeFromSuperview];

                                              //...                                           
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                              NSLog(@"tabsView removed from Superview. Objects Deleted.");
                                              [self showTabs]; 
                                              NSLog(@"TabDelete finished. Button removed and tabsView updated accordingly.");

                                          }
                          ];    
                     }];
```

And this is the showTabs method which was already called when I started the app:

-(void)showTabs {

```
NSLog(@"showTabs started...");

currentView = @"Tabs";

if ([tabsClippedView isDescendantOfView:self.view]) {
    NSLog(@"There is already a tabsClippedView.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"There is no tabsClippedView. I'll add one...");
    [self initTabsClippedView];
}

if ([tabsView isDescendantOfView:tabsClippedView]) {
    NSLog(@"There is already a tabsView");
} else {
    NSLog(@"There is no tabsView for the buttons. I'll add one including buttons.");
    [self initTabs];
}
```

Comment: Post code on how you are creating your subviews and where you are accessing them.

Comment: @Praveen S: I posted more code on how I created my subviews and where I access them. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I noticed that you accepted the answer that provided a solution, without understanding it, rather than taking the time to understand the answer that explained the problem. I updated my answer to provide a few more solutions, all better than Praveen's. Praveen certainly provided the easiest solution and you can just use that and go on with your life, but for your own sake I think you should take the time to understand what you're doing. FYI: It is possible to change the accept if you find my answer to be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you are getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`? Is it possible that the app is crashing because `tabsView` is deallocated when you send `isDescendantOfView:` to it. If you run with breakpoints enabled it should tell you the reason for the crash. If it is an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` problem you should try `NSZombie`.

To activate NSZombie do the following:

1. Get info of the executable.
2. Go to the arguments tab.
3. In the "Variables to be set in the environment:" section add:

Name: NSZombieEnabled
Value: YES

Then run your app as usual and when it crashes it should tell you which deallocated object received what message.

**EDIT:** Just saw your edit. I think I nailed it. You're autoreleasing the views when you create them, so when they are removed from their superviews they are no longer retained and thus deallocated. You're app crashes because you're trying to run methods on deallocated views.

**EDIT 2:** Thought I should tell you that there is a better solution than the one posted by Praveen S.

Change your code as follows:

```
[tabsClippedView release];
tabsClippedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tabsClippedFrame];
```

and

```
[tabsView release];
tabsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tabsFrame];
```

The above code does the same thing as the code posted by Praveen S, but without the autorelease. An autorelease is more expensive than a regular release and should only be used when needed and in this case it isn't.

Rather than releasing before you allocate a new view you probably want to release the view when you're done with it:

```
[tabsView removeFromSuperview];
[tabsView release];
tabsView = nil;
```

or simply

```
[tabsView removeFromSuperview];
self.tabsView = nil;
```

and then instead of:

```
if ([tabsView isDescendantOfView:tabsClippedView]) ...
```

you can use:

```
if (tabsView) ...
```

As you might have noticed, there really is no need for you to retain the view. You could just as well do the following:

```
tabsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tabsFrame];
[tabsClippedView addSubview:tabsView]; // This retains tabsView
[tabsView release];
```

and then to remove the view you would use:

```
[tabsView removeFromSuperview]; // This will release the tabsView
tabsView = nil;
```

Also remember to set the views to nil in `viewDidUnload`.

**EDIT 3:** Why self made such a difference:

What you need to understand is how properties and reference counting works. There are books and such you could read about it. I'm sure Google can provide you with some good references as well.

The difference between

```
self.tabsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

and

```
tabsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

is that `self.tabsView` is accessing the properties setter, while `tabsView` is accessing the instance variable directly.

A nonatomic, retain property's implementation looks something like the following:

```
- (void)setTabsView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (view != tabsView) {
        [tabsView release];
        tabsView = [view retain];
    }
}
```

So the property is taking care of the memory management for you. In my solution I take care of the memory management myself and thus I don't need the property to do it for me, so I don't use it.

I hope this explains why self made such a difference.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I just added 'self' as Praveen S suggested and that fixed the problem. Is that also the solution to the problem you diagnosed? I'm still unsure about the use of self and it sounds as if your explanation tells me why I should have used self... don't know. I'm a bit confused now (even though really happy that it works now). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @n.evermind What self does here is that it uses the property instead of accessing the instance variable directly. This only solves the problem if your properties are declared (and implemented) as retain properties.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I am beginning to understand this now. However, as far as I understand you, I don't need to retain my views, so in my header, I would need to change the following: `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *tabsView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *tabsClippedView;`
 to assign instead of retain, right?

Comment: @n.evermind Unless you need access to the views outside of the controller you don't really need the properties at all. I would however advice against changing the properties from retain to assign. View properties are expected to be retain properties and the retain/assign keyword only affects the setter, which you don't use anyway. So the only effect changing the property to assign would have is to confuse future developers.

Comment: Also, I still can't see how a single self made such a difference. You are not using self at all... so why is this suddenly working? Is the main solution just that I release the tabsView once I'm done with it and assign nil to it? Is that really the gist of it all? Was I before crashing the app because the tabsView was still floating around deallocated?

Comment: @n.evermind I updated the answer to include why self made such a difference. So that should answer the first question. Your other questions all have the same answer: Yes. So it seems like you understand what happened now.

Comment: @n.evermind Just a little notice: When you're trying to use something that is deallocated the app will crash with the message EXC_BAD_ACCESS. In this case it was pretty easy to figure out why, but when it isn't, `NSZombie` can help you figure it out and save you a lot of time and unnecessary headaches. So remember this the next time you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: This is excellent stuff. Thank you so much for your assistance, help, patience and kindness. I read a book on Objective-C (by Kochan), but I'm afraid that it won't stay in my head unless I am confronted with real problems and need to fight with the code.

Comment: @Erik B: Sorry to keep bothering you with this, but you wrote: An autorelease is more expensive than a regular release and should only be used when needed and in this case it isn't. -- I just opened up another question and people usually agree that it is NOT more expensive (in terms of memory usage)... or did you mean to say something different? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860639/autorelease-for-beginners).

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as follows:

```
self.tabsClippedView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tabsClippedFrame] autorelease];
```

and

```
self.tabsView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tabsFrame] autorelease];
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much... I guess the main problem is that I'm still unsure about the use of self. What exactly is the difference between using it and not using it? I mean in this case it is lethal not to use it, so I hope this will be a good lesson for me in terms of its use.

Comment: Its all about reference counting, a auto release decreases reference count by 1 and in your case i am guessing the subviews have a retain property. Probably you may want to read a blog post which i will be writing soon on the same. I had major issues with reference counting.

Comment: Thanks. A blog post on the issue would be indeed very much appreciated. Are there already some discussions about this topic here on stackoverflow? Where do you blog?